# JS Datables jquery sorting in one column with multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a column in my data table which can have one of 4 values:

```
[0] -> Elegant
[1] -> Basic
[2] -> Business
[3] -> Sport
```

In data tables I can sort only DESC or ASC is it possible to every time I click on name of column it will sort by different value?

Thank you very much

Comment: so you need.. on 1st click it sort on basis of elegant, 2nd click need to sort on basic and so...?

Comment: 3nd click i need business 4nd click sport and 5nd click again form 0